# Items ordered empty - Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2.4

I can't figure out why Items ordered is not shown in my orders. I'm running Magento 2.4. I can see them in my invoice. Basically everywhere but in my order.
I see that it does count the number of items, due to the number of  on inspection.
[image: Example]

Does anyone have a clue as to why this is ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked through my local setup of Magento 2.4 .

All good.

Please set your site in developer mode and if you can share error log from var/log/ files then it would be great to solve.

If this helps then hit like.

Enjoy coding :) !!!

Hiren Patel

Comment: I've added my debug.log, exception.log and system.log in this wetransfer link: https://we.tl/t-adT9c55D2F Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If You are customise invoice. Check All error log. Share me.

Second Try this way :-

```
composer update
```

Clear caches and generated content

```
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/cache/*
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/page_cache/*
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/generated/code/*
```

Second solution is Your are not customise.Follow above way..

Any query let me know.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: I've just tried to do as above, and still, nothing appears in my orders. The thing is, I can't find anything related to the problem in my logs, you can see them in the above comment. I added the wetransfer link.